# Experimental Demonstration of Entanglement?

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, polarization, bells-inequality

In many papers about entangled sources, they use an experimental setup like this one to demonstrate their entanglement:

[image]

The setup involves measuring coincidences at the detectors at various angles of the two half-wave plates (HWPs). Experimentalists seem to do two things with these setups to demonstrate that their source is producing entangled photons:

1. Show that the entanglement visibility $V > 1/\sqrt{2}$. To do this, keep one waveplate fixed at angle $\theta_1$ and rotate the other (let its fast axis have angle $\theta_2$), and observe coincidences that follow a behavior proportional to $V\cos^2(\theta_1-\theta_2)$, where $V$ is the entanglement visibility.
2. Show that the CHSH parameter is greater than 2. In this setup that means combining coincidence counts from all four detectors (in various combinations) for four different settings of the two waveplates according to the CHSH formula.

My question is: are both of these necessary to show that your source is entangled? For instance is there a state that gives the $\cos^2$ dependence but doesn't violate CHSH, or violates CHSH but doesn't give the sine-squared dependence?

I was able to come up with a state that somewhat satisfies (1) but not (2). A mixed state where half the time you produce $|HV\rangle$ and half the time $|HH\rangle$ will produce a coincidence count that goes like $\cos^2\theta_2$ on the detectors. Notably, the argument is $\theta_2$ alone, not $\theta_1-\theta_2$, so there is a different behavior and you can show that this isn't entangled by trying to produce this curve at two different values of the fixed waveplate. Indeed many papers do produce the $\cos^2(\theta_1-\theta_2)$ curve at different values of $\theta_1$ which.

And if I mix a Bell state with a maximally mixed state, *both* the CHSH parameter *and* the visibility will decrease, so that again looking at both parameters seems redundant.

Comment: You should be able to get a similar pattern by mixing a Bell state with something separable (e.g. the maximally mixed state). At some point this will become separable. (BTW it might be easier to answer if you would write formulas for what is measured; then one does not have to think first about the correct formula before cooking up examples.)

Comment: I was being a bit lazy when I first posted... I've added in a figure and a bit more math, which may help. I think if I mix in the maximally mixed state, both my visibility will decrease *and* my CHSH parameter will decrease, right? I'm wondering if there's a situation where the CHSH quantity will be above 2 but the visibility will be too low, or vice versa - or are these redundant measures?

Comment: Well, I think clear formulas will (i) show that you have properly thought about the problem (and, in particular, have a clear definition of what it is), and (ii) take the burden of working out these things, checking what precisely people mean by visibility, etc., from potential answerers. (I don't see a clear formula right now: This would say *what* is being measured (i.e. measurement projectors, or the like), and what quantity is then computed from that.)